# how i can insert elements in the div from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, data-structures

This is my html here i am taking elements from user and trying to update in js.

This my script file

```js
  // Initializing the Stack Class
    
        function Stack() {
            this.dataStore = [];
            this.top = 0;
            this.push = push; // Inserting the element in Stack
            this.pop = pop; //Removing the element in Stack
            this.peek = peek;
            this.clear = clear;
            this.length = length;
        }
        
        // Adding an element in Stack
        function push(element) {
            this.dataStore[this.top++] = element;
        }
        
        function peek() {
            return this.dataStore[this.top - 1];
        
        }
        
        // Removing an element from the given stack
        function pop() {
            return this.dataStore[-this.top];
        }
        
        function clear() {
            this.top = 0;
        }
        
        function length() {
            return this.top;
        }
        
        var s = new Stack();
        
        function pushToStack(el){
            s.push(el);
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
  <html lang="en"> 
  <head> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"> 
  <title>Document</title> 
  </head> 
  <body> <!-- <div> <input type="text" id="stackName"> <button onclick="MakeStack()">Make a stack</button> </div> --> 
  <div> 
    <input type="text" id="elemet"> 
    <button onclick="pushToStack(document.getElementById('elemet').value)">
      Push an elemet
    </button> 
  </div> 
  <div class="container"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script> 
  </body> 
  </html>
```

What i want is that when i click on push button the data from text filed should save in array as stack and data  should show in container as my element of Stack. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

append the input to the `Container`, here is the code. Hope this is what you are looking for.

```js
// Initializing the Stack Class

    function Stack() {
        this.dataStore = [];
        this.top = 0;
        this.push = push; // Inserting the element in Stack
        this.pop = pop; //Removing the element in Stack
        this.peek = peek;
        this.clear = clear;
        this.length = length;
    }

    // Adding an element in Stack
    function push(element) {
        this.dataStore[this.top++] = element;
    }

    function peek() {
        return this.dataStore[this.top - 1];

    }

    // Removing an element from the given stack
    function pop() {
        return this.dataStore[-this.top];
    }

    function clear() {
        this.top = 0;
    }

    function length() {
        return this.top;
    }

    var s = new Stack();
    function pushContainer(el){
      //console.log(el);
      var x = document.getElementById("container");
      x.appendChild(el);
    }
    function pushToStack(el){
      //
      var newElement = document.createElement("p");
      var Textnode = document.createTextNode(el);
      newElement.appendChild(Textnode);
      pushContainer(newElement);
      
      
      s.push(el);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  
</head>
<body>
 <div>
        <input type="text" id="elemet">
        <button onclick="pushToStack(document.getElementById('elemet').value)">Push an elemet</button>
    </div>
    <div id="container">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks ,but these error is showing on console   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Comment: `but these error is showing on console Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null` Which error are you taking about ? @PankajJaiswal

Comment: I have changed the container to `id`, if you want the container to be `class` just add the following code `document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].appendChild(el)`;

Comment: Thanks it worked , but there is error on console can you short it out , please !!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your push function as :

```
function pushToStack(el){
    s.push(el);
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  var node = document.createTextNode(el);
   para.appendChild(node);
   document.querySelector('.container').appendChild(para);
}
```

for working code, please refer:[this pen](https://codepen.io/shubhamYerawar/pen/xapggR?editors=1011)

Comment: its working in pen.io but not working on my machine, even i pasted whole code

Answer (score 0):

Modify your push function then:

```
function push(element) {
    this.dataStore[this.top++] = element;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.textContent = element;
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: Corrected, didn't see you have an id instead of class on the div and due to you naming the variable `element` I thought that would be an HTMLElement already.